# Calling conventions for stack based structures in ARM?

Tags: c, struct, arm

How are stack based structures passed to subroutines in ARM assembly?

For example:

```
typedef struct SomeStruct { 
    uint32_t one;
    uint32_t two;
    uint32_t three;
    uint32_t four;
} SomeStruct;

void SomeFunction(uint32_t someValue, SomeStruct someStruct, uint32_t otherValue);
```

In this case, how would the structure be passed? My guess is:

- `r0` - `someValue`
- `r1` - `someStruct.one`
- `r2` - `someStruct.two`
- `r3` - `someStruct.three`
- `*sp` - `someStruct.four`
- `*sp,#4` - `otherValue`

*Is that correct or does something else happen?* **Or does it just pass the structure's** `sp` **based address?**

Comment: Now that I think of it, my guess sounds really stupid.

Comment: Unless your struct is really small, it's not very common to pass structs directly.  If you just pass a pointer to the struct there will be less overhead to call the funciton.

Comment: @TJD: that's problematic, though, because the argument logically is a copy. So if the caller does `SomeFunction(1, my_global_struct, 1);` and the callee does `if (&someStruct == &my_global_struct)` then of course that must be false. So the calling convention can pass a pointer, and it might help, but it might be the callee still has to take a copy, in which case it's no less overhead.

Comment: @SteveJessop, yes if you really need a copy then you will have to pay that price

Comment: You can always make the copy yourself.  Define your function as `void SomeFunction( uint32_t someValue, const SomeStruct *someStruct, uint32_t otherValue )` and then within your function define `SomeStruct copy = *someStruct;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a "procedure call standard" for an ARM ABI here: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/IHI0042D_aapcs.pdf

There's more than one ABI for ARM, and more again for 64 bit ARM, but just looking at this one, the relevant section is "5.5 Parameter Passing". At a glance, I think C.5 says you're right, this struct will be split between r1-r3 and the stack.

B.1, which can replace an argument of composite type with a pointer to a copy in memory, never applies in C, since both caller and callee must have `SomeStruct` as a complete type in order to pass by value.

Comment: I haven't looked at the ARM ABI in particular, but it's very common to handle the passing and return of structures by having the caller pass the address.  If the called function is written in C, the address won't get exposed to user code; instead the compiler will often generate code to copy the struct.  If a routine is only called once, it would be better for the caller to do the copy, but most routines get called enough times that it's more efficient for the called code to do the copying.